# Oracle Text Contains and Numbers with Separators

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, lexer, oracle-text

I'm using a ctxsys.context index on one column to facilitate the Oracle Text full-text 
search feature. But having a problem when indexing numeric values that are separated by ',' or '.'.

I created the index like:

```
create index my_index on my_table(my_column)
indextype is ctxsys.context parameters ('SYNC (ON COMMIT)');
```

Then I insert four text documents:

```
insert into my_table (id, doc) values (1, 'FOO 300 BAR');
insert into my_table (id, doc) values (2, 'FOO 300 BAR 1,000.00');
insert into my_table (id, doc) values (3, 'FOO1FOO');
insert into my_table (id, doc) values (4, '1 FOO');
```

Now I would like to use the contains operator to search for 'FOO 300 BAR', '1,000.00' and a combination of both:

```
select score(1), id from my_table where contains(doc, 'FOO 300 BAR', 1) > 0;
select score(1), id from my_table where contains(doc, '1,000.00', 1) > 0;
select score(1), id from my_table where contains(doc, 'FOO 300 BAR 1,000.00', 1) > 0;
```

First one works as expected and I get both id 1 and 2 as a result. Although when I try to use 1,000.00 I get 0 rows as result.

As I read from the documentation it is using BASIC_LEXER as default. I also tried to specify the separators explicitly on the lexer and applied it to the index.

```
begin
ctx_ddl.create_preference('my_lex', 'BASIC_LEXER');
ctx_ddl.set_attribute('my_lex', 'numjoin', '.');
ctx_ddl.set_attribute('my_lex', 'numgroup', ',');
end;

create index my_index on my_table(doc)
indextype is ctxsys.context parameters ('SYNC (ON COMMIT) LEXER my_lex');
```

But I experienced the same behavior as before.

Could someone explain how Oracle Text treats numbers with separators and how I could configure the index so that separated numbers are treated as single words?

I'm using Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Answer (score 1):

I am using Oracle 10g and I had the same issue you described with one minor difference.

I used this script:

```
    begin
      ctx_ddl.create_preference('my_lexer', 'BASIC_LEXER');
      ctx_ddl.set_attribute('my_lexer', 'numjoin', '.');
      ctx_ddl.set_attribute('my_lexer', 'numgroup', ','); 
      ctx_ddl.set_attribute('my_lexer', 'printjoins', '-/"_'); 
      ctx_ddl.set_attribute('my_lexer', 'index_text', 'YES'); 

    end;
```

And this to create the index:

```
Create Index my_table_TIX01 ON my_table (doc) INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT PARAMETERS('lexer my_lexer SYNC (ON COMMIT)')
```

This query returns 1 row in my case:

```
select score(1), id, doc from my_table where contains(doc, '1,000.00', 1) > 0;

SCORE(1),ID,DOC
2,4,1 FOO
```

The problem is how the tokens in the string you search for are parsed. Basically 1,000.00 is divided into multiple tokens: 1 then 000.00. You can experiment with this by inserting these rows:

```
insert into my_table (id, doc) values (5, '00 FOO');
insert into my_table (id, doc) values (6, '000.00 FOO');
commit; -- Dont' forget to commit the data you insert otherwise the index is not updated!
```

then run this query:

```
select score(1), id, doc from my_table where contains(doc, '1,000.00', 1) > 0;
```

It comes back with:

```
SCORE(1),ID,DOC
3,4,1 FOO
3,6,000.00 FOO
```

The comma is the same as the ACCUM. This is from the documentation (see the links at the bottom):

> ACCUM     ,   Use the ACCUM operator to search for documents that contain
>   at least one occurrence of any of the query terms. The accumulate
>   operator ranks documents according to the total term weight of a
>   document.     The following query returns all documents that contain the
>   terms dogs, cats and puppies giving the highest scores to the
>   documents that contain all three terms:
>
> 'dogs, cats, puppies'

To fix your search you need to enclose the string you search for between curly brackets:

These two queries will return the data you expect:

```
select score(1), id, doc from my_table where contains(doc, '{1,000.00}', 1) > 0;
select score(1), id, doc from my_table where contains(doc, 'FOO 300 BAR {1,000.00}', 1) > 0;
```

One more thing to be aware of is that if you search for 300 FOO, i.e. you run this query:

```
select score(1), id, doc from my_table where contains(doc, '300 FOO', 1) > 0;
```

it won't come back with anything. You either have to use relaxation templates or use AND or &:
Examples:

```
select score(1), id, doc from my_table where contains(doc, '300 and FOO', 1) > 0;

select score(1), id, doc from my_table where contains(doc, '
    <query>
       <textquery lang="ENGLISH" grammar="CONTEXT">
         <progression>
           <seq>300 f00</seq>
           <seq>300 NEAR f00</seq>
           <seq>300 AND foo</seq>       
         </progression>
       </textquery>
       <score datatype="INTEGER" algorithm="COUNT"/>
    </query>
    ', 1) > 0;
```

See also these links:

- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/text.102/b14218/cqoper.htm#CCREF0300
- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/text.102/b14217/query.htm#i1006507
- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/text.102/b14218/csql.htm#i997503

I think we are very used to searching google and this doesn't work exactly as google does...